# How to remove an empty line between two navbars

Tags: html, css

I have 2 nav bars which I want to be on top of each other without spaces, but for some reason there is an empty line as if I had used 
.

HTML part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>Logo!
<BR>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">placeholder</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">placeholder</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">placeholder</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">placeholder</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">placeholder</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#">subheader1</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">subheader2</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">subheader3</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS part:

```
.submenu {

text-align: left;

background-color: #C2F0C2;

}

.menu {

background-color: #98bf21;

}

body {

width: 900px;

margin: 2em auto;

}

.menu ul {

margin:0;

padding:0;

overflow: hidden;

text-align: center;

font-size:0;

}

.menu li {

display: inline;

list-style: none;

}

.menu a:link, a:visited {

display: inline-block;

margin-right: -4px;

width: 135px;

color: #FFFFFF;

font-size: small;

font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;

text-align: center;

padding: 4px;

text-decoration: none;

background-color: #98bf21;

}

.menu a:hover, a:active {

background-color: #7A991A;

}

.submenu ul {

margin:0;

padding:0;

overflow: hidden;

text-align: left;

font-size:0;

}

.submenu li {

display: inline;

list-style: none;

}

.submenu a:link, a:visited {

display: inline-block;

margin-right: -4px;

width: 135px;

color: #000000;

font-size: small;

font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;

text-align: center;

padding: 4px;

text-decoration: none;

background-color: #C2F0C2;

}

.submenu a:hover, a:active {

background-color: #7A991A;

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C3Sjq/100/)

I'm not sure which part I need to change so I included all of it.

How can I remove the empty line?

E: I failed with the fiddle and forgot to press update, should have the right one now.

Comment: which browser? chrome it is working fine\

Comment: IE, it is for a company website so needs to have IE compability.

Comment: this is different fiddle

Comment: Yeah my bad, should have the correct fiddle now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply `padding:0` and `margin:0` for your `menu` and `submenu` classes.

```
.menu, .submenu{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C3Sjq/101/)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add this in your CSS :

```
.menu {margin-bottom:0px;}
.submenu {margin-top:0px;}
```

Have a good day.

Answer (score -1):

Note: I see on firefox all together, so it give me 2 pixels on the two square join. For that i used this technique

You can use pseudo `:last-child`

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    margin: 0;
    white-space:0;
}

div:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid red;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/C3Sjq/99/)**

Comment: It's about two `<ul>` that have a `margin`. Your answer still has whitespace between the elements. If you look at the `<p>` tag you are using, it has margin around it.

Comment: @putvande ... the fiddle that shows on the question was the one i used...meanwhile he change it to reflect the real ...my all answer was based on a wrong jsfiddle...sorry!